# Rcpp long vector support

Tags: r, package, rcpp

I was wondering if there is a way to make sure that my package which uses Rcpp can work with long vectors on machines that have long vector support and still work on machines that don't have long vector support?

I read in the Rcpp FAQ that one needs to add a CXX_STD = CXX11 flag to src/Makevars to force C++11 compilation, and add a system requirement for it in the description file.

My question is will this mean that users require C++11 to install my package? If so is there a way to make this a conditional requirement so that long vectors are supported where possible?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Long-vectors

Comment: Nothing special is needed these days.  R switched to defaulting to C++11 a few releases ago (in R 4.0.0 if memory serves).  With R 4.2.0 the standard became C++14, with R 4.3.0 (the current series) it further increased to C++17.  All this of course depends on having a new enough compiler.  So in short things shsould already be on for you.

Comment: Thanks both! That's very useful to know and thanks again for the amazing Rcpp package.